# How to calculate user's info completeness in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem in my new rails project.I want to implement a function which can show the user's info completeness by a bar like Linkedin.

I think I can use a variable to record the completeness,but I don't have any idea about how to calculate it.

P.S I have two ***Model***,one is the ***User Model***,another is the ***Info Model***.

[image: a picture from Linkedin,show the completeness bar]

Comment: Could it be a % of fields filled out?  So if you have 20 fields and 10 of them are blank, then progress is 50%?   So have a progress function in the info model.  It then iterates over all the fields and counts how many are blank.  Then returns the percentage.

Comment: This isn't a question about how to do it in rails. It is about subjective suggestions on a yet undefined calculation metric. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: It's not about rails,I have change the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is, in fact, completely arbitrary. It's based entirely on which activities on the site you want to encourage.

A couple of mechanisms you can consider:

- Model "accomplishments" with a completed/not completed status. Count up the ones you care about. Store the accomplishments based on activity either as they happen or at the end of the day in some batch job. For each user, calculate the percentage with the usual math (accomplishments completed/sum of available accomplishments) * 100 = percentage.
- A variation of the same, but weighted based on what you consider more valuable contributions. In this case, the math is basically sum of (weight n * accomplishment n)/total weight.
- The previous Careers.stackoverflow.com model made a geeky joke about Spinal Tap by making it possible to have counts greater than 100%. You can do that simply by undercounting the maximum accomplishments.